# How to find the area of a shape whose sides are made up of line or arc of circle?

Tags: geometry

The arc and lines form the sides of the shape.
The sides touch each other at end point in such a way that each end point can touch only one shape
and the shape is closed

eg:- line--arc--line--line--line--arc--arc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**
Make them all lines and get that area, and then add the areas of the parts of circles cut off by the circle arcs by lines where that circle part was cut off. If a circle arc bends inward, subtract that area.

Comment: but how to know if the circle was bent inwards

Comment: I got a logic if we take the mid point of the arc and see if the point is inside the shape made by the lines I think it is possible to say if the point is inside or outside the shape. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, that would work-- if arc midpoint inside the line shape then it bends inward, so that circle sector area gets subtracted. This assumes that the figure made by using all lines is such that (1) inward arcs stay inside the line shape, and (2) outward arcs do not cross each other.